# What to do if I need to check older NVidia driver than available in repositories

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I have Ubuntu 17.10 and I have [problems with my GTX 1080](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1030326/linux/gpu-fallen-off-the-bus-while-running-more-demanding-demos-or-games). I need to check it with older driver (v375), but there are only version 384, 387 and 390 in Ubuntu repositories. I can download the driver directly from NVidia site, but how to install it without breaking my system? And with possibility to revert to drivers from Ubuntu repository in the future?

And, I need to check some older kernel version as well.

Comment: …specifically “the first way” in [Mitch’s answer](/a/508255/175814).

Comment: On which kernel are you now (see the output of `uname -r`)? Did you try other kernels? Did you try other versions of the Nvidia graphics driver, specifically those mentioned in your question? It would be much easier for you if one of them turns out to be fine since you can then just install the package from the repositories. There are also v304 and v340 in the [Proprietary GPU drivers PPA](https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+packages?field.name_filter=nvidia&field.status_filter=published&field.series_filter=artful).

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I'am on kernel version 4.13.0-36-generic. I have tried all three versions from 17.10 repository, no luck with any of them.

Comment: I meant, that I want to be able to return to driver from repository after trying that downloaded from Nvidia. I realized, that is has its own uninstall option however. So I can probably uninstall it manually and install repository driver after.